# Not able to implement Notification service

Tags: java, android, notifications

I referred following links to study the demo example on Notification service in Android : [Sai Geetha Blog](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2009/09/android-developer-tutorial-for.html) and [Vogella Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidNotifications/article.html#notificationmanager_example).

Both worked but partially i.e. I've downloaded both projects as it is and executed them. Both has button to initiate the notification. On Button Click notification appears at the top status bar.

Here comes the problem, on click of that notification, neither any message is getting displayed nor intent is getting fired to navigate to new activity.

I'm new to this concept so any help appreciated...

***CODE***

**CreateNotification .class**

```
public class CreateNotification extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    public void notify(View view) {
        NotificationManager nm= (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        final int UNIQUE_ID = 123458;
        Intent navigationIntent = new Intent();
        navigationIntent.setClass(CreateNotification.this,
                NotificationReceiver.class);

        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, navigationIntent,
                0);
        String body = "New Notification added!!!";
        String title = "Title";
        Notification n = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, body,
                System.currentTimeMillis());
        n.number = 2;
        n.setLatestEventInfo(this, title, body, pi);
        n.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
        nm.notify(UNIQUE_ID, n);
    }
}
```

---

**NotificationReceiver.class**

```
public class NotificationReceiver extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.result);
        Log.i("Receiver", "NotificationReceiver");
    }
}
```

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:onClick="notify"
        android:text="Create Notification" >
    </Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

**result.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is the result activity opened from the notification" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.notificationmanager"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".CreateNotification"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".NotificationReceiver" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Please attach your AndroidManifest.xml file as well.

Comment: Hmmm ... everything looks good. Please download the API demos ... you can find some notification examples in it. Link: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/index.html#Notification

Comment: Demo only discuss about displaying notification title, What happens after clicking that title is not explained :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try to modify the row:

```
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, navigationIntent, 0);
```

to

```
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, navigationIntent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Documentation:

Note that the activity will be started outside of the context of an existing activity, so you must use the Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK launch flag in the Intent.

Attached below my code. For me it is working properly.

```
private void showNotification() {
    Log.i(TAG, "showNotification called...");
    final Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, UpdateApplicationActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    final PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

    final Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.htc_notification, getString(R.string.UpdateCheck_update_available), System.currentTimeMillis());
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE | Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, getString(R.string.UpdateCheck_notification_title), getString(R.string.UpdateCheck_notification_message), contentIntent);

    // Notifying the user about the new update.
    if (notificationManager != null) {
        notificationManager.notify(APP_UPDATE_NOTIFICATION, notification);
    }
}
```